# Batch update FCM token while migrating to a different firebase account

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey i'm just stuck in this problem:

I have a database full of FCM (Firebase cloud message) tokens which were created using an old firebase account/project setup. I also have user's deviceId, as well as a the server key which is used to send push messages. This setup works fine in order to send massive push campaigns I have everything I need to, but I am migrating from this old firebase account to a plenty new one, so my new firebase account will have a totally new server key, then no FCM token that I already have will work properly til all users update their app version in order to have the new firebase setup credentials and update their FCM token (which is updated as soon as they login). Do you guys see any easy way to migrate whole fcm tokens from one firebase account to another in a lighter way?

I've been thinking that we should keep two versions of FCM tokens and migrate users as they download new version of the app, organically, but the problem is it might take a long time and my push campaign tools are not that flexible, they work with only a specific Server Key, which i'd have to change to the new one sooner or later.

Any ideas? Thank you so far!

Tried to find a way to update FCM tokens massively but couldn't find any.